# FTRUNCATE leaves space at the beginning

Tags: php, file

I want to truncate a file with each loop and write again. So, I am using below code.

However, what is happening here is I am getting some extra space at the beginning in each loop. There is no space as 1st time no space is being added (also I tried trim function).

Can you please help me?

```
$file = fopen("progress/".$_POST['fname'].".txt","w");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    updateDB($row['movieid'],trim($row['tempname']));
    ftruncate($file,0);
    fwrite($file,round(100*$complete++/$tot));
}
fclose($file);
```

**OUTPUT: (something like this)**

```
11
  20
    30
      40
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to move the file pointer back to the beginning. `ftruncate()` does not do this for you. Writing to an advanced position fills the preceding bytes with `NULL`. 
Use [`fseek()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php).